# What to do with perhaps spammy tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Consider, please, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/info

To my ear, there's some pretty loud horn-tooting here.

However, I don't want to just edit it out, in case I'm just a grump.

What to do?

Comment: Well, it's copy-pasta from that product's front page. Remove it for plagiarism if not for spam?

Comment: Yup, I concur with @Mat - most of these "spam sounding" tag wikis are really direct copy and paste from the product's home page / elevator pitch, and shouldn't be in the tag wikis in the first place. I don't think anybody *intentionally* spams tag wikis - they're too obscure for that

Comment: As a copy directly from their promotional material I'd agree it should be at least edited to be a neutral explanation, rather than a sales pitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit them to sound less like ads.

Or suggest an edit if you don't have the reputation to edit directly.

Comment: Rep I got. SMExpertise I lack.